# How to change border color in Flutter according to the value?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a container widget with a border of a certain color.
I want to be able to change the color of the border if the entered value in a TextField is greater or less than some value. What would be the best way to acheive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Define a `_color` variable in your class:

```
Color _color = Colors.purple;
```

2. Assign the `_color` variable to the `Container`'s border:

```
                   Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          width: 5.0,
                          // assign the color to the border color
                          color: _color,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

3. Test if your condition is met in the `onChanged` callback of the `TextField` and change the `_color` according to your needs:

```
                    TextField(
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        if (newValue.length > 5) { // test for your condition
                          setState(() {
                            _color = Colors.red; // change the color
                          });
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            _color = Colors.blue; // change the color if the condition is not met
                          });
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your TextField COntroller;

```
final yourTextFieldControler = TextEditingController();
```

Just getValue From controller and change to int.

```
Container(
   
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: yourTextFieldControler.text.toInt > 5 ?  Colors.red:Colors.blueAccent)
  ),
  child: Text("My Awesome Border"),
)
```

**This is your TextField**

```
TextField(
  controler : yourTextFieldControler,
         onChanged: (newValue) {
setState((){})
}
```